# Rspec, ensuring a method is called on a Rails controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have some 3rd party library included in my application controller.

```
require 'new_relic/agent/method_tracer'
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
end
```

I want use it in my other controllers, for example in my SearchController

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    add_method_tracer :show, 'Custom/FU'
end
```

I know, I can check via rspec for the existence of the method provided by the library in the controller:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SearchController do

  it "has newrelic method tracer enabled" do
    SearchController.should respond_to :add_method_tracer
  end
end
```

But this solution doesn't check the proper method arguments.

How I can ensure (test via rspec) the SearchController has the:

```
add_method_tracer :show, 'Custom/FU'
```

line present, and it is called with proper arguments ?

Simply said, I want a test, which fails when somebody removes by accident the add_method_tracer from the controller... AND... I want ensure, the method is called with proper arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this gem, but I took a look [at the code](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb#L369) and found that [it checks](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/master/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb#L510) if it already did what it is supposed to do using `trace_method_exists?`.

So you could try something like this:

```
it "is tracing #show on metric Custom/FU" do
  expect(SearchController.trace_method_exists?(:show, "Custom/FU")).to be_false
end
```